# Multiple steps form with Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I followed the tutorial to build the multiple step form using [UI Router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router) , it worked well, however now I would like to prevent from page reloading action, if user stays at 2nd step, and reload whole page, it should be redirected to first step, and required him to input to first step form first.

I have no idea to reload the page to the first step with that requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can check the status with a flag in your first step.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply look at the current state and do basic validation on the data object. If the values are empty then force the state back to the first state.

```
 if($state.current.name != "form.profile" && (!$scope.name || !$scope.email)){
  $state.go("form.profile");
}
```